# Grounding sensitive devices (ICs, logic level switches) in a vehicle (generator and battery) environment

Tags: digital-logic, grounding, automotive, 12v

In my project vehicle I will be using a buck converter that can take from 9 to 18V and output clean 12V. I will also need smaller regulators (12v to 5v) for couple of microcontrollers. I've heard something about star grounding that prevent interferences, but I lack knowledge about it, not sure if that applies to me.

Anyhow, the common 12V battery will feed the main buck converter, and that main buck will have another 12 to 5 connected to it. Microcontroller will have few logic level switches, would it be a mistake to ground those switches to chassis? My "hunch" tells me it would make more sense to create a ground bus on the 5V buck, since the microcontrollers will use 5V.

What would be the correct practice to ground in this scenario, what makes a difference grounding something to chassis or battery, should I just make sure the grounding and potential are the same, 12v to 12v? Or would a 3.3 microcontroller device work proper if grounded to vehicle chassis?

Answer (score 1):

In a vehicle you really have no choice - ground IS the chassis. You can get your 0V from the battery or the chassis - they’re tied together with heavy wires.

I’d suggest you have a look at the wiring diagram of a late model vehicle to get an idea of how the manufacturers resolve your issue. The average vehicle has a number of electronic control units switching high currents and reading sensors, so you’b be wise to follow their lead. There’s also a number of SAE standards that address your issues.

In short, if your device is simply powered from the vehicle and has no other interaction with it, then you can get 0V via the chassis or via  other wiring.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll find a modern vehicle diagram. BUT :D I do have to say, in ideal scenario without thinking about wiring cost or length our routing - would it be better to use 5V buck converter ground (neg) to ground 5V devices?

Comment: I can’t see how using a buck converter would make any difference to grounding. If it were an isolated converter then it might have merit but you’ll find car ECUs are unlikely to use an isolated converter for their mcu power supply. The car chassis gives you a very low impedance ground path, so where do you think the noise is going to come from to upset your micro? Remember current flows in a loop.

Comment: The currents flowing in a loop is important. While the chassis is the ground, having return paths via chassis may create large loops, and if multiple different devices with high currents use the same path, there will be some electrical noise.

Comment: I am a toddler in these topics so bare with my ignorance :D the way I look at it (and I'm aware I'm far behind on the topic) it just sounds wrong to use chassis ground on a 3.3V powered microcontroller and its logic signals - it sounds more "logical" to make a ground bus from the 3.3V output on a isolated dc dc converter, and I will be using the isolated converters only, not just simple voltage dividers or anything. In this case having one buck convert 12 to 5 and one 5 to 3.3 - wouldn't it make sense to use grounds from each of those bucks for anything hooked up to them?

Comment: You need to quantify what your concern is with using chassis ground. Isolated converters are not quite the magic bullet you think they are. I learnt the hard way when I had problems with 300kHz signals from the converter being injected into my isolated ground that upset my comms. Car ECUs rarely would use an isolated converter or even optocouplers - they are simply not needed in the majority of cases. What else apart from the power gets connected to the vehicle?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/6aU5NEu.jpg - here you can see a general overview of what will be running in the vehicle. It might look overkill to put a converter for 12V on a battery...but that's because the 12V controller needs clean 12V and battery power can oscillate due to rpm and such, so I figured smoothing it out to proper 12 would be good idea. The rest of devices is pretty simple, just need to figure the proper grounding for each.

Comment: What is a 12V controller?  Your diagram makes little sense to me. If you’re using isolated converters, what needs to be grounded?

Comment: It's a device (controlled by Arduino) handling 12V loads via smart high-side switches, so it needs a clean 12V fed into it. The 12V loads (lights) will be grounded to chassis. But the Arduino itself needs to be powered via 5V (to prevent its wonky LDO from stepping 12 to 5) so the isolated DC 12V output buck could feed 12v->5v buck and that 5V negative could be used to ground the Arduino, rather than chassis? Would this be a correct practice?

Comment: Definitely not common practice. You seem to think there is something magical about the vehicle chassis being used as ground. In order to control your high side drivers, the Arduino will need to share the same ground, so isolated supplies do nothing for you. Go to a self serve car wrecker and get yourself some ECUs - body management computers are close to what you’re doing and look at what they do.